# Redis dump to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, redis

I want Redis to store data and dump all information in PostgreSQL every 5 minutes, for example, or if more than 50 keys were changed. How I could do this?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I'm a beginner in this kind of tasks and I'm wondering if there some solutions?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Why do you want to do this? Redis already has very good [persistence features](http://antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html). Look at those.

**2)** If you are sure that you want to do this (I am not), you'll have to convert your data from one scheme to another: data in a key-value store (Redis) has to be organized in an entirely different way than in a relational database (PostgreSQL). The complexity of this conversion depends on the exact nature of the data and has to be performed by custom code.

Comment: I want this because it's faster to make one "insert" instead of 1kk "inserts" in loop and "selects" too if I understand it right. And I want to store data in redis first, get data from redis and in a while update the table in DB.

Comment: The question is: why do you need an RDBMS in addition to Redis?